# Mass Effect 3 won't save new career but does save existing career

Tags: mass-effect-3

The situation is as follows:

- Mass Effect 3 is downloaded through origin, located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Mass Effect 3`
- The save folder is located at `E:\BioWare\Mass Effect 3\Save`
- Mass Effect 2 has the same setup (but should not matter)

I have an existing career already at that save location. Loading and saving for that career works. However when I try to create a new career, both from scratch and with importing, no new save is created, nor is the character folder created in the save folder.

I have tried setting Location in the `GamerSettings.ini` both to nothing (original value) and to `E:\BioWare\Mass Effect 3\Save`.

My Save folder has the right permissions, Mass Effect should be able to create a new folder there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so apparently this is simply once again the 'well known' issue where you can't (easily) have ME2/3 installed on a different partition than your Documents partition. As far as I could conclude after trial and error this issue only occurs when saving a career for the first time, it apparently can't create the appropriate directory. I'm actually astonished that BioWare never solved this, I remember this being an issue when ME2 came out first.

How I got around it:

- Copy everything under the current Save directory to the install directory's Save folder (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Mass Effect 3\BIOGame\Save`). Do not forget the `Local_Profile.sav` file, or you won't get any bonuses for the 'replay'.
- Launch the game with the -nohomedir option, this should work via Origin (right click > game properties...) or otherwise you should edit a desktop shortcut for ME3 to add that option.
- Start the new career, an initial save game should be created immediately after you finish your character and when the opening credits begin.
- Quit the game
- Copy everything back from the game's folder to your wanted save game folder
- Remove the -nohomedir option
- Play as usual

The moving back isn't really necessary but I did it because I like to keep my save games on that location and not mixed in with the program files.